# Android - Interstitial full screen ad does not react

Tags: android, admob, fullscreen, interstitial

In my Android App (HTML5, Webview) I want to use a interstitial full screen ad. To ad is loaded successfully, it is shown, but unfortunately the ad is not reacting on any interactions (touches), like

- click on the ad -> to be forwarded to the advertiser
- close the ad -> back to the app

Only the "back key" from Android is working.

Certainly, this is not acceptable from the user’s point of view.

I already tried

- various test ads,
- using 2nd device to ensure that the behaviours does not result from a "test device" settings.
- I did not find any issues in the log files (at least no crashes)
- banner ad (=shown on the same screen) works perfectly fine (clicking on ad->I am forwarded to advertiser)

I used the following code to initialize the ad/framework:

```
MobileAds.initialize(getApplicationContext(), "ca-app-pub-75007419xxxxxxx~7207yyyyyyy");  
AdRequest adRequest = new AdRequest.Builder()
                        .addTestDevice(testDevice)
                        .build();
mAd_screen = new InterstitialAd(getApplicationContext());
mAd_screen.setAdUnitId("ca-app-pub-75007419xxxxxxx/76137yyyyyyy");
mAd_screen.loadAd(adRequest);
```

to show Ad:

```
if (mAd_screen!=null && mAd_screen.isLoaded()) {
   mAd_screen.show();
}
```

Expected result would be, that the full screen ad reacts in a similar way like the banner ad:

- clicking on the add -> fowarding to the advertiser
- closing add (e.g. via icon presented in one of the corners) -> back to app

What I found in the logs, when I am clicking on the ad:

```
04-03 15:03:55.033 2840-2925/? D/InputReader: Input event(7): value=1 when=16508820098000
04-03 15:03:55.034 2840-2925/? I/InputReader: Touch event's action is 0x0 (deviceType=0) [pCnt=1, s=0.2245 ] when=16508820098000
04-03 15:03:55.034 2840-2924/? I/InputDispatcher: Delivering touch to (677): action: 0x0, toolType: 1
04-03 15:03:55.035 677-677/? D/ViewRootImpl@a4a620d[AdActivity]: ViewPostImeInputStage processPointer 0
```

So, it seems that the touch event is recognized but no action defined/takes place....

Comment: Check in your manifest if you have the following - `android:launchMode="singleInstance"`

Comment: Unfortunatley nothing changed... But thanks for the proposal.
BTW: I just added something I found in the logs.